# crontab wget works but throws permission error

Tags: php, cron

Im using a cron tab every 1 minute to test if it works via the following command:

wget http://www.site.com/cron.php

which works great but on my email i get the following response:

```
Resolving www.site.com... 11.11.11.11
Connecting to www.site.com|11.11.11.11|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 0 [text/html]
delete_tut_viewers.php: Permission denied

Cannot write to `cron.php' (Permission denied).
```

so can i leave it like that or do i have to check for another solution?

thanks.

Comment: What is the working directory of the cron entry?  You probably have add a `cd`  before the `wget`:  `(cd /home/somewhere/safe; wget ...)`

Comment: if i add cd before wget i get this error: /bin/sh: line 0: cd: wget: No such file or directory

Comment: @fxuser:  `cd` needs a parameter of the directory to change to.  See my example above.  It is necessary to put the `cd` and the `wget` within parenthesis as is the semicolon which separates them.

Comment: like (cd path/to/folder/of/scrip; wget cron.php)

Comment: I tried this and it fails, (cd httpdocs/inc/crons/; wget cron.php)
and it reports Resolving cron.php... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `cron.php'

i also tried (cd http://www.example.com/inc/crons; wget cron.php)
which email me with
cd: http://www.site.com/inc/crons: No such file or directory
/cron.php: Unsupported scheme.

how can i fix it?

Comment: @fxuser:  did you include `http://www.site.com`?  That is, it should include the full URL.  Likewise, the `cd` command might need the full path, since I (at least) don't know cron's default working directory, and I'd be concerned it might change with migration to another machine, or a software upgrade.  Therefore, a plausible entry would be `(cd /var/www/html/httpdocs/inc/crons/; wget http://www.example.com/somedirectory/cron.php)`.  Clearly, if `/var/www/html` is not correct for the system, replace it with the appropriate absolute path (begins with `/`).

Comment: thanks , as i see it works but then it creates a new file and saves it as .php.1 file and continues with 2,3,4 each time the cron runs.
why does that happen?is there any way to delete the file it creates?

Comment: It might be the point at which to put the logic into a shell script, or even a program.  The `wget` command does you a favor by choosing an unused local name.  If the original version isn't wanted, add a delete command (`rm filename`) before downloading another.  Or perhaps it makes sense to move the previous file(s) somewhere else, or rename them out of the way.  If there is a system administrator, he or she probably has some useful ideas.

Comment: so by adding rm cron.php will delete the previous file and create a new one with the save content of the previous file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding it to the root crontab (`sudo crontab -e`) or change permissions of the directory where you want to store wget's result (by default `wget` wants to store the contents of the file it gets to its current working directory).

Comment: i guess i cant change the permissions of the folder because that will make the folder exploitable since its a web app... ill take a look on the command...

Comment: Running something that fetches arbitrary files from the web isn't a good thing to be running as root.

Comment: so if i leave it as it is will there be any security problem until i get a better solution?